# How can I do check syntax error of python in gvim in unix with python3.5?

Tags: python, unix, vim

I use with gvim and has auto checking python syntax. but it defines to python2.7. I want to change it to python3.5.
How can I do it ?
I use pylint or pylink

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode?

Comment: No. I use pylint and it points to python2.7. I want to change it to python3.5 @Alex

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340940/installing-pylint-for-python3-on-ubuntu).

Specifically for your problem I would change the pylint executable in /usr/local/bin/pylint to use python3,

Just replace **#!/usr/bin/python2** with **#!/usr/bin/python3**

So the file contents should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pylint import run_pylint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(run_pylint())
```